# How to find the nth term of this sequence?

Tags: sequences-and-series, arithmetic

How do I find the $n^{th}$ term, and what is it?

$$ 1, \dfrac{1}{4}, \dfrac{1}{9}, \dfrac{1}{16}, \dfrac{1}{25},\dots$$

I mean I want to find out the relation how $n^{th}$ term depends on $n$. I'm really stuck on this question.

Comment: Note that $1,4,9,16$ are all consecutive perfect squares. Then we take the reciprocals. So we have $a_n = \frac{1}{n^2}$.

Comment: Technically, there doesn't need to be a pattern at all. But reciprocal squares seems to make the most sense.

Answer (score 1):

Unless this is a trick question, the answer is $$\frac{1}{n^2}.$$ Then the sequence continues $$\frac{1}{36}, \frac{1}{49}, \frac{1}{81}, \frac{1}{100}, \frac{1}{121}, \frac{1}{144}, \frac{1}{169}, \frac{1}{196}, \ldots$$

If you look up just `1, 4, 9, 16, 25` in the OEIS, you will get more than a hundred results. But the very first result will be [A000290, The squares: $a(n) = n^2$](https://oeis.org/A000290). Often the first and simplest explanation is the best.